# Is it possible to "copy" one layer from WMS and create another WMS only with this layer automatically?

Tags: qgis, wms, php, qgis-server, lizmap

I'm using Lizmap and QGIS to create WMS service with multiple layers. Now I need to find a way to create WMS containing only one layer that the 'main' WMS contains.

Is there any way to do it without creating another QGIS project?

I tried &layers request with GetMap, but QGIS still sees every layer regardless of which layer name I used in request.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want to have a "single" layer in the WMS GetCapabilities showing ALL layers in your QGIS project ? (so users can't select a subset) ? Is the option "group as a layer" in the Lizmap plugin, "layer tab" an option ?

Comment: `tried &layers request with GetMap`, layers is a required parameter with GetMap, so this statement is ambiguous, perhaps you requested the root layer, and therefore get all contained layers?  Can you provide the GetCapabilities response showing all layer names